# Create Custom Workflow Action using Visual Studio

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio

I want created a custom workflow action with Visual Studio.

I use this [link](http://rtmgroupq8.com/en/create-custom-workflow-action-using-visual-studio) and created a new custom workflow . When i deploy solution , i don't find custom action in Custom action list in SPD.

**How do create Custom Workflow Action using Visual Studio?!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post has information on the topic in more detail : http://blogs.3sharp.com/2011/11/03/creating-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-activity-in-visual-studio-2010/

See the steps here if you missed anything